# CSS - word-wrap and word-break logic

Tags: html, css, web

I've been reading a lot but I can't seem to understand the difference between `word-wrap: break-word` and `word-break: break-word` (note: I don't use CJK languages so differences in that respect are irrelevant to me).

Actually, I can see differences in the way they act: `word-break` breaks in the middle of words if it has to, considering the width of its ancestors. `word-wrap` on the other hand only cares about its own width. It will not break if the element's width exceeds its parent's width. This seems strange to me. Is that really the difference between the two?

See examples here:

`word-break` works: https://jsfiddle.net/hh6a03cy/7/

`word-wrap` doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/hh6a03cy/6/

```
<div style="display: flex; font-size: xx-large;">
  <span>woohoo</span>
  <div style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top">gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
  </div>
</div>
```

Related question: [CSS - inline blocks side by side with 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805880/css-inline-blocks-side-by-side-with-100-width)

I want to really understand how both `word-wrap` and `word-break` work (especially `word-wrap`) but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Thank you

Comment: The word-wrap property specifies whether or not to transfer long words that do not fit in the width to the specified area. This property is of a rough nature and when validating the document in CSS3 produces an error.


The word-break property specifies how to do the wrapping of strings within words that do not fit the width in the specified area.


https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#word-wrap

Comment: @Dmitriy Lishtvan So I should never use `word-wrap`? What is it for?

Comment: It turns out that yes, i can write an answer?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "do not use" thing? The official site doesn't say that. Also I still don't get how exactly `word-wrap` works.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break and here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp word-break has no "break-word" value,it is something created by Chrome.

And the reason your `word-wrap` is not working is because you haven't set the width of the div.Here is the working version of thy code https://jsfiddle.net/hh6a03cy/8/ with word-wrap

Comment: Is there any documentation for `word-break: break-word`? Also my question is mainly about `word-wrap`. And here it doesn't work even with width defined (ancrstor's width): https://jsfiddle.net/hh6a03cy/9/

Comment: Yeah but why? `word-wrap` ignores parent's width? How come